# AWS boto3 - how to run a spot instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I am currently do this to start an EC2 on-demand instance from a lambda function:

```
 ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-east-2')

 instances = ec2.create_instances(
    ImageId='ami-0c709cc4edbf9a8c0', 
    MinCount=1, 
    MaxCount=1,
    KeyName="mykey",
    InstanceType="m4.large",
    IamInstanceProfile={'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::231412431243:instance-profile/myimage'},
    UserData=user_data_script
```

Is there a property I can add here which would run this as a spot instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a parameter in the [`create_instances()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.create_instances) command for spot instances:

```
    InstanceMarketOptions={
        'MarketType': 'spot',
        'SpotOptions': {
            'MaxPrice': 'string',
            'SpotInstanceType': 'one-time'|'persistent',
            'BlockDurationMinutes': 123,
            'ValidUntil': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'InstanceInterruptionBehavior': 'hibernate'|'stop'|'terminate'
        }
    },
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, 'MaxPrice' is a string in USD. For instance, if you wanted the max price of the spot instance to be $1, you would do `'MaxPrice': '1',`